# Должен ли я использовать @JoinTable вместе с @ManyToMany если я использую flyway?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-jpa, flyway

У меня возник вопрос, должен ли я использовать

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
```

если я использую flyway?

Или будет достаточно просто:

```
@ManyToMany
```

Comment: flyway служит для миграций бд. Гибер строит свои запросы на основе аннотаций, который ему дает программист. Ответ прост: аннотации нужны и их нужно описывать полностью.

Comment: @Tsyklop спасибо : )

Comment: Хотя я и не знаю, что такое фливей, но считаю, должен.